# Tor Circuits vs Channels vs Connection

Tags: circuit

With respect to Tor source code, what is the different between 
1- Circuits
2- Channels
3- Connections

And how do they relate to each other? Thanks.

Comment: As was suggested on your [similar question](https://tor.stackexchange.com/questions/14101/tor-multiplexing): Have a read of the [Tor Specification](https://gitweb.torproject.org/torspec.git/tree/tor-spec.txt), particularly sections 5 and 6 ("Circuit management" and "Application connections and stream management").

Comment: Also from said question "Streams are multiplexed inside of circuits, circuits consist of cells, cells for circuits are sent multiplexed across a TLS tunnel between nodes."

Comment: Hi, I already went through the specs many times. The words "circuit" and "channel" are used interchangeably there. However, from the code, they are not. I see that circuits have channels attached to them and they have different structures, also connections are a separate structure. Channels are attached to circuits somehow. Im intrested in understanding that relation and if it is 1-n or m-n, etc. My previous question was abiut streams, not channels. Thanks in advanced

Comment: *"I already went through the specs many times. The words "circuit" and "channel" are used interchangeably there."* The word *"channel"* appears in the spec 0 times. In the code it's literally documented in the comments: https://gitweb.torproject.org/tor.git/tree/src/or/channel.c?id=tor-0.2.9.9#n7 what about this don't you understand?

Comment: @canonizingironize If channel is not documented in the specs, then there is no point of going over the spec to find an answer to my question. I want to know the difference between a channel and a circuit, and how do they relate to each other and work with each other to deliver cells

Comment: "Streams are multiplexed inside of circuits, circuits consist of cells, cells for circuits are sent multiplexed across a TLS tunnel between nodes." The TLS tunnel is a "channel".

Comment: None of these comments make a distinction between a channel and a connection. It's a good question, too bad it was never answered.

Answer (score -1):

Channels *usually* mean client-requested TCP pipes, the very good example of channel is [SocksPort](https://www.torproject.org/docs/tor-manual.html.en#SocksPort) options like *IsolateDestAddr* and *IsolateClientAddr*. So - Channels are related to the client requests *channeled* through Tor

Circuits are the node-to-node chains for *whatever* purpose, i.e. reaching the Clearnet via Exit node or connecting to HiddenService. Circuits are transferring onions and usually noted as "Node A" -> "Node B" -> "Node C". It's an *internode* communication pipes for whatever reason.

Connection means a TCP connection as it is - regardless of the place it is made-of/accepted-at : it is a client-to-socks, client-to-TransPort, node-to-directory, node-to-node etc. It's *just* a connection

Comment: I literally pointed to what a "channel" is in the comments directly above this answer and you *still* got it *wrong*, Alexey.